# Changing name value on radio button (bootstrap)

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap

The goal is to create four inline radio buttons, with a button to submit the form to a simple php script. The problem is that changing the name attribute from 'optradio' to something like 'small' breaks the switching between buttons.

The html:

```
    <form action="logo-tshirt.php" method="post">
        <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="small" value="1">S</label>
        <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" checked name="medium" value="1">M</label>
        <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="large" value="1">L</label>
        <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="extra-large" value="1">XL</label><br />
        <input style="margin-top:5px" type="submit" value="Buy With PayPal" name="send" class="btn btn-primary">
    </form>
```

The php:

```
<?php
if($_POST['small'] == 1 ){ 
    header("Location: http://www.google.com"); 
} 
elseif($_POST['medium'] == 1 ){ 
    header("Location: http://www.yahoo.com"); 
} 
elseif($_POST['large'] == 1 ){ 
    header("Location: http://www.bing.com"); 
} 
elseif($_POST['extra-large'] == 1 ){ 
    header("Location: http://www.bbc.co.uk"); 
} 
else { 
    header("Location: http://www.theguardian.co.uk"); 
} 
?>
```

Thanks for all the answers. The one i used was AI.G's because it used the least lines of code. This is my working code.

```
<form action="logo-tshirt.php" method="post">
    <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="optradio" value="small">S</label>
    <label class="radio-inline"><input checked type="radio" name="optradio" value="medium">M</label>
    <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="optradio" value="large">L</label>
    <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="optradio" value="extra-large">XL</label><br />
    <input style="margin-top:5px" type="submit" value="Buy With PayPal" name="send" class="btn btn-primary">
</form>
```

The php:

```
<?php
switch ($_POST['optradio']) {
    case "small": header("Location: http://www.google.com"); break;
    case "medium": header("Location: http://www.yahoo.com"); break;
    case "large": header("Location: http://www.bing.com"); break;
    case "extra-large": header("Location: http://www.bbc.co.uk"); break;
    default:header("Location: http://www.theguardian.co.uk");   /* if $_POST['option'] was none of the above */
}
?>
```

Comment: Radio button need to have the same name to be a group, what you need to do is change the value of each radio and compare in PHP. `$_POST['my_radio'] == 'google'` `$_POST['my_radio'] == 'yahoo'` ...

Comment: Why would you keep different names for the same radio group? Change the name to may be "size" and then change the values to "small, medium, large" respectively. Then in your php `$_POST['size']` will have the size string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All radios should have the same name but different values:

```
<label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="option" value="small">S</label>
<label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" checked name="option" value="medium">M</label>
<label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="option" value="large">L</label>
<label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="option" value="extra-large">XL</label>
```

Now check them using a switch:

```
switch ($_POST['option']) {
    case "small": /* redirect to google */ break;
    case "medium": /* redirect to yahoo */ break;
    /* etc... */
    default:
        /* if $_POST['option'] was none of the above */
        /* redirect to somewhere else */
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You have it a little bit wrong. The radio buttons must have a common `name`, and their `value` is what actually is sent to the server. Example :

```
<form action="a.php" method="post">
   <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="buy" value="small">S</label>
   <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="buy" checked value="medium">M</label>
   <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="buy" value="large">L</label>
   <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="buy" value="extra-large">XL</label><br />
   <input style="margin-top:5px" type="submit" value="Buy With PayPal" name="send" class="btn btn-primary">
</form>
```

Now you can extract the chosen value by $_POST

```
if ($_POST['buy'] == 'small' ){ 
    header("Location: http://www.google.com"); 
}
```

...etc